# What would be a good dry yeast equivalent to Wyeast 3787?

Tags: yeast

I'm looking to produce high gravity strong Trappist like beer.
Wyeast 3787 seems to be a good choice, but I'm looking for a dry yeast alternative. Suggestions?

I'll make a starter before pitching if required.

Comment: Is there something more specific regarding WY3787 you could ask?  Your question is looking for generalities and opinions.  Not something that fits in the SE Q&A format.

Comment: Wyeast 3787 is one of the recommend yeast for trappist according to my knowledge. However, it comes as a "liquid" yeast. Building one or to starter or pitching a lot of packs is required for high gravity beers. This is why I would like to use a dry yeast : generally less costly, and more active yeast cell by ml easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one might be an option for you. I have not used it myself, but read in various forums that it is a good option.

http://www.fermentis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Safbrew-S-33-en.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I found this other one from the same manufacturer, which is advertised as 'recommended to brew a diversity of beers amongst which abbey style beers known for their high alcohol content' : http://www.fermentis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Safbrew-BE-256-en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think that a Fermentis Safbrew T-58 would be a close match.

Comment: Appropriate answer as well, upvoted.